# Docker ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image and when the docker build reaches the tensorflow-cpu requirement, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu (from socialworks-nn==0.0.7->-r requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu (from socialworks-nn==0.0.7->-r requirements.txt (line 16))
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN apk --no-cache add git
RUN apk add mariadb-dev

WORKDIR /socialworks-api

COPY . /socialworks-api

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

May I ask what should I run to install tensorflow? My application must run on Python 3.6. I am new to Docker, this is my first build. Also, I have tried commenting out tensorflow, but I am receiving the same error with numpy.

I have also tried running this command in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

But after that, I would receive this error:

```
ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that in order to install tensorflow-cpu, I need to use `FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.1.0-py3` or `FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04`
But using one of these, the size of the image gets really big.